# How to use OPENSSH private key to access server?

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, ssh-keys

I received a private key in plain text format from someone. How do I save it to access server. It's in a format mentioned below.

```
-----FOR SERVER! BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEcccccBG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZrrrrrttAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
etc etc 
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the key to a file and use your SSH client:

```
ssh -i <path_to_key> user@server.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this guide helped -> https://www.simplified.guide/putty/convert-ssh-key-to-ppk

The only problem with key was the extra text "FOR SERVER! ", after deleting that I was able to convert key to .ppk file and use it